# Detect the caret ( ^ ) key on keyPressEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qkeyevent

I am currently developing an application in which I have implemented the `keyPressEvent` function.

I would like to detect when the user presses the `^` (caret, usually `Shift + 6` on a US Keyboard) key, for which I cannot identify it from the names of the keys provided by Qt (`Qt::Key_`).

Is the key available for detection? If not, how can I implement its detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the key event like this:

`.h`:

```
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e);
    ~MainWindow();
```

`.cpp`:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e)
{
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_AsciiCircum)
    {
        qDebug() << "yep !";
    }
}
```